# Как определить, где определяемое слово, а где приложение?

Tags: грамматика

Лишь один из сыновей — Михаил узнал это.

Как определить, где определяемое слово, а где приложение?

Comment: Обособленное приложение с одной стороны не отделяется. Так что здесь только один вариант остаётся.